# Explanation of ! relational operator

Tags: objective-c

I don't understand the use of ! operator in if (! origin). The author explained that it's testing the instance variable origin to see if it's value is nonzero, but I don't quite understand what that means.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYPoint : NSObject 
@property int x, y;

@end
```

---

```
#import "XYpoint.h"

@implementation XYPoint
@synthesize x, y;

@end
```

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class XYPoint;
@interface Rectangle: NSObject

-(XYPoint *) origin;
-(void) setOrigin: (XYPoint *) pt; 
@end
```

---

```
#import "Rectangle.h"
#import "XYpoint.h"

@implementation Rectangle {
    XYPoint *origin;
}

-(void) setOrigin:(XYPoint *)pt {
    if (! origin)
    origin = [[XYpoint alloc] init];

origin.x = pt.x;
origin.y = pt.y
}
-(XYPoint *) origin {
    return origin;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!` is usually used to test for `not`. Most often you'll find it used when testing a conditional that should evaluate to true or false. The `!` operator will then reverse that value.

It's often common for anything other than false, 0, or nil (or null depending on language) to be considered true. For example if I have `x = 5` and I test `if (x)`, the if statement's true condition will be executed as `x` simply has a value other than false or nil.

In this particular case it looks as if `origin` is a pointer to an object. Therefore, if it is pointing to an object it will have a non nil value of an integer pointer (something like 0x??????). So `(! origin)` is testing, 'does my variable origin point to another object, or is it nil.' If so, the code determines it is acceptable to assign a new value to origin. However, if origin was previously set, this code will not assign a new value to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is testing if the value is initialized (pointer not equal to 0; operator `!` is equivalent to **NOT** operator in Objective-C).  If object `origin` of class XYPoint is allocated it will point to address of the object instead of 0.

Kind regards,
Bo

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it just checks whether origin has been initialized. Uninitialized pointers are 0x0, which is basically 0, which is equal to false at assembler level.

Answer (score 0):

! means 'not' so "if (!origin)" translates as "if not origin" and is testing whether origin has a value.  This operator will vary in meaning between languages but in Objective-C, (!origin) will return true if origin is set to 0.  It must have been declared otherwise your code will crash.  In dynamic languages you can use this operator to test whether a variable has been declared as well whether it holds a value.